# Three dimensional integration: $\int d^3p \exp(-i\frac{p^2}{2m}t)\exp(i \vec{p}(\vec{x}-\vec{x_0}))$

Tags: integration

This is my first time in stackexchange. I hope someone can help me how to calculate the following integration (I have already the solution, but I don't know how to get there):
$$\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int d^3pe^{-i\frac{p^2}{2m}t}e^{i\vec{p}(\vec{x}-\vec{x}_0)}=\left(\frac{m}{2\pi it}\right)^{3/2}e^{im(\vec{x}-\vec{x}_0)^2/2t}$$

I don't understand how this solution can be achieved: I thought that integrating over the Euler function wouldn't change the exponent of the Euler functions. But it does here. I would integrate the space components separately like

$$\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int dp_xdp_ydp_ze^{-i\frac{p_x^2+p_y^2+p_z^2}{2m}t}e^{i(p_x(x-x_0)+p_y(y-y_0)+p_z(z-z_0))}$$

but here I must admit that I don't understand how to integrate over something like $~~e^{x^2+x}$.

Thank you for your answers in advance!

Comment: The integrand doesn't decay to $0$ as $\|p\|\to\infty$, so is this a distributional thing? Or is the $i$ in the quadratic exponent erroneous?

Comment: @runway44. Yes, this should be interpreted in a distributional sense. It's a Fourier transform of a bounded and $C^\infty$ function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note your integrand is a product of functions of $p_x,\,p_y,\,p_z$, so your integral is a product of integrals over these variables. So let's just worry e.g. about $$\int_{\Bbb R}dp_x e^{-i(p_x^2-2m(x-x_0)p_x/t)t/2m}=e^{im(x-x_0)^2/(2t)}\int_{\Bbb R}dqe^{-iq^2t/2m},$$where $q:=p_x-m(x-x_0)/t$. (Those familiar with the physics this problem is about will know the convention $\hbar=1$ keeps the exponents dimensionless.) Analytically continuing $\int_{\Bbb R}dqe^{-Aq^2}=\sqrt{\pi/A}$ from $A>0$ to $A\in\Bbb C$ rewrites the integral over $q$ as $\sqrt{\frac{2\pi m}{it}}$. You can put it all together now if you're careful with the powers of $2\pi$ in the normalizations.

Comment: I got very far with your help, thank you! But I have problems with the power of $2\pi$: I got $(2\pi)^{1/2}$, because of $\sqrt(\frac{2\pi m}{it})^3$(because of three integrations) multiplied with $\frac{1}{2\pi}$. What is wrong about that? Another question: I think there are two mistakes in your formula: shouldn't it be $p_x$ instead of $p_z$ on the left of the equation in the exponent, second summand? And $(x-x_0)^2$ instead of $(x-x_0^2)$ on the right?

Comment: @Kathi Thanks for the last point; I've fixed that. I can't see anywhere that I've used $p_z$, though. Note that since $\frac{1}{2\pi}\sqrt{\frac{2\pi m}{it}}=\sqrt{\frac{m}{2\pi it}}$, the $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ in front of your triple integral should have been $\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}$.